# PHP, Easiest way to find a relative path from an absolute path

Tags: php, regex

let's say i have an absolute path : `/myproject/web/uploads/myfolder/myfile.jpg`

i'm searching to determinate a relative path fom a part of the absolute path, like this:

```
<?php

echo relative_path('/myproject/web/uploads/myfolder/myfile.jpg', 'web/uploads');

// print "myfolder/myfile.jpg"
```

Comment: I don't get it, how can you associate from an part of an path to an relative path?

Comment: please define relative path in your understanding

Comment: What would the answer be with: `relative_path('/myproject/web/uploads/myfolder/backup/2/web/uploads/myfolder/myfile.jpg', 'web/uploads');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you just want the part from the absolute path that is after the given part:

```
function relative_path($absolute, $part) {
    $pos = strpos($absolute, $part);
    return substr($absolute, $pos + strlen($part) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function relative_path ($absolute, $part) {
  return (($rel = strstr($absolute, $part)) !== FALSE) ? ltrim(substr($rel, strlen($part)),'/') : FALSE;
}
```

Returns a string with the relative path (as described above) or `FALSE` on failure.

This function is by no means fool proof, as any function that attempted to do the task you outlined above would be. Consider the following:

```
$absolute = "/dir/someplace/dir/someplace/somedir/file.ext";
$part = "dir/someplace";

// Returns "dir/someplace/somedir/file.ext" when you may in fact want "somedir/file.ext"
relative_path($absolute, $part);
```

I suspect what you really need to do here is to re-think what you are actually trying to do...

Comment: works but i prefer the simplicity of @arnaud576875, anyway thanks